# Scheduling a class/bean using quartz trigger?

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

I am using `Spring3`. I have a bean which needs to be scheduled. My application produces `Jar` not `war`. Do i need to deploy the jar in tomcat to trigger the job?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Definitely not. If you are using Quartz to schedule and execute your job(s), then you can use it in standalone Java applications as well. In your Spring config you should have something like this (assuming your are using a JDBC job store to persist your jobs and triggers):

```
<!--
  QuartzDesk scheduler.
-->
<bean id="scheduler"
    class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">

  <property name="schedulerName" value="YourSchedulerName"/>

  <property name="autoStartup" value="true"/>

  <property name="waitForJobsToCompleteOnShutdown" value="true"/>

  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>

  <property name="overwriteExistingJobs" value="true"/>

  <property name="quartzProperties">
    <props>
      <prop key="org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId">${scheduler.org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId}</prop>
      <prop key="org.quartz.scheduler.instanceIdGenerator.class">${scheduler.org.quartz.scheduler.instanceIdGenerator.class}</prop>
      <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass">${scheduler.org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass}</prop>

      <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix">${scheduler.org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix}</prop>
      <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered">${scheduler.org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered}</prop>
      <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.selectWithLockSQL">${scheduler.org.quartz.jobStore.selectWithLockSQL}</prop>
      <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.lockHandler.class">${scheduler.org.quartz.jobStore.lockHandler.class}</prop>

      <!--
        The "use properties" flag instructs JDBCJobStore that all values in JobDataMaps will be Strings, and therefore can be stored as name-value pairs, rather than storing more complex objects in their serialized form in the BLOB column. This is can be handy, as you avoid the class versioning issues that can arise from serializing your non-String classes into a BLOB.
      -->
      <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.useProperties">true</prop>

      <!--
        The the number of milliseconds the scheduler will 'tolerate' a trigger to pass its next-fire-time by, before being considered "misfired". The default value (if you don't make an entry of this property in your configuration) is 60000 (60 seconds).
      -->
      <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold">60000</prop>

      <!--
        Configures Quartz to expose the scheduler through an MBean in the JMX MBeanServer.
      -->
      <prop key="org.quartz.scheduler.jmx.export">true</prop>

      <!--
        The scheduler thread will be marked as a daemon thread.
      -->
      <prop key="org.quartz.scheduler.makeSchedulerThreadDaemon">true</prop>
      <!--
        The scheduler thread pool threads will be marked as daemon threads.
      -->
      <prop key="org.quartz.threadPool.makeThreadsDaemons">true</prop>
    </props>
  </property>

  <property name="jobFactory">
    <bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SpringBeanJobFactory"/>
  </property>

  <property name="jobDetails" ref="jobDetails"/>

  <property name="triggers" ref="jobTriggers"/>

  <!--
    Name of the property in the scheduler context the Spring application context
    will be exposed through.
  -->
  <property name="applicationContextSchedulerContextKey" value="applicationContext"/>
</bean>

<!--
  jobDetails list contains all jobs that will be added to the QuartzDesk scheduler.
-->
<bean id="jobDetails" class="java.util.ArrayList">
  <constructor-arg>
    <list>
      <ref bean="yourJob1"/>
    </list>
  </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<!--
  jobTriggers list contains all triggers that will be added to the QuartzDesk scheduler.
-->
<bean id="jobTriggers" class="java.util.ArrayList">
  <constructor-arg>
    <list>
      <ref bean="yourTrigger1"/>
      ...
    </list>
  </constructor-arg>
</bean>


<bean id="yourJob1" class="org.quartz.impl.JobDetailImpl">
  <property name="jobClass" value="your job fqcn"/>
  <property name="group" value="someJobGroup"/>
  <property name="name" value="YourJob1"/>

  <property name="description"
            value="Job that does this and that..."/>

  <property name="durability" value="true"/>

  <property name="jobDataMap">
    <bean class="org.quartz.JobDataMap">
        <constructor-arg>
          <map>
            <entry key="param1" value="value1"/>
            ...
          </map>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
  </property>
</bean>


<bean id="yourTrigger1"
      class="org.quartz.impl.triggers.CronTriggerImpl">
  <property name="name" value="YourTrigger1"/>
  <property name="group" value="someTriggerGroup"/>
  <property name="jobName" value="YourJob1"/>
  <property name="jobGroup" value="someJobGroup"/>
  <property name="description" value="CRON trigger."/>
  <!-- ss mm hh day-of-month month day-of-week year -->
  <property name="cronExpression" value="some cron trigger expression"/>
</bean>
```

This will create a Quartz scheduler bean with the specified list of jobs and triggers. The scheduler will be started automatically upon your application startup.

You will notice that the above app context snippet uses property placeholders for certain values. You will need to expand these placeholders with valid values. Please refer to Quartz documentation for details. In most cases you can fall back on default values.